# SQL Server left join same table twice I'm getting duplicate rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have this query:

```
SELECT
    u.UserId,
    up.PhoneNumber AS OfficePhoneNumber,
    up2.PhoneNumber               
FROM 
    [OnlineTools].[App].[User] AS u
LEFT JOIN 
    [UserPhone] AS up ON up.UserId = u.UserId 
                      AND up.PhoneType = 'Work'
LEFT JOIN 
    [UserPhone] AS up2 ON up2.UserId = u.UserId 
                       AND up2.PhoneType = 'Mobile'
```

Expected result is three records returned and its correct when I left join one `UserPhone` table only.

When I'm joining the same table again to get the mobile phones, instead of three records I'm getting 18 records.

What I can improve here in order to get the correct records?

Comment: Can you simply not add `DISTINCT` in the `SELECT` if you are simply getting them three columns?

Comment: Difficult to say when we cannot see your data. Can you add some sample data please

Comment: This is exactly how JOIN works. For example 3 Work *  6 Mobile = 18 rows.

Comment: Nope - there are NOT true duplicate rows. If you think there are, then add the PK values of all three tables into your query to understand your assumption and why it is not correct. Most likely a user has multiple "work" or "mobile" numbers.

Comment: Why don't you join on `and up.PhoneType in ('Work', 'Mobile')` ?

Comment: I agree with @SMor: to use a concrete example let's say you have 3 users each with 1 office phone but each with 2 mobile phones, your query would be expected to return 6 rows, since each user is repeated for each office phone and each combination of user and office phone is then repeated for each mobile phone.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that for each user there is 1 work phone and 1 mobile phone, you could use conditional aggregation instead of the 2 joins:

```
SELECT u.UserId,
       MAX(CASE WHEN up.PhoneType = 'Work' THEN up.PhoneNumber END) AS OfficePhoneNumber,
       MAX(CASE WHEN up.PhoneType = 'Mobile' THEN up.PhoneNumber END) AS MobilePhoneNumber
FROM [OnlineTools].[App].[User] AS u LEFT JOIN [UserPhone] AS up 
ON up.UserId = u.UserId 
GROUP BY u.UserId;
```

Comment: Yes. Use `MIN` or `MAX` to get one phone number per type or use `STRING_AGG` to get the list of phone numbers per type.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting a cross-join (or Cartesian result).  For each entry in the "Work" condition, it is getting all entries in the "Mobile" since they are left-joins.  Then, the inverse is true while getting all Mobile, joining to the work.

I would suggest joining ONCE to the given phone table and filter on just the two types, but add a column to SHOW what type it was...  Something like

```
SELECT
    u.UserId,
    up.PhoneNumber,
    up.PhoneType
   FROM 
      OnlineTools.App.User u
       JOIN UserPhone up 
          ON u.UserId = up.UserId
         AND up.PhoneType in ( 'Work', 'Mobile' )
```

This way, it is a single entry retrieved, AND that specific type is the column to show if work or mobile.  Now, if you want the work phone to be listed in the first position, just add

```
order by
   up.PhoneType DESC
```

Which will result in all WORK phones first, then any mobile... but if there are no work phones, then only mobile will show (or vice-versa).